# Scrapy format breadcrumbs using xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am crawling through a site using Scrapy and I want to format the extracted breadcrumbs to create a site path:

HTML:

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs"><li><a href="/site/ID/home">Home</a></li> <li><a href="/site/ID/AboutUs">Who We Are</a></li></ul>
```

What am doing:

```
breadcrumb = response.xpath("//ul[@id='breadcrumbs']")[0].extract()
```

What I get right now:

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs"><li><a href="/site/ID/home">Home</a></li> <li><a href="/site/ID/AboutUs">Who We Are</a></li></ul>
```

What I really need:

```
/home/AboutUs/
```

Any idea how I should write the xpath or how I should format the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all the `href` values using `//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li/a/@href` xpath, extract the endings using [`.re()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) them.

Example from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html 
>>> ''.join(response.xpath('//ul[@id="breadcrumbs"]/li/a/@href').re(r'^.*?(/\w+)$'))
u'/home/AboutUs'
```

`^.*?(/\w+)$` would match any characters followed (`?` means it is a "non-greedy" matching type) by a slash followed by one or more alphanumeric characters (and `_`). Parenthesis help to [capture](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) the last part of the string (slash and aplhanumeric characters). `^` and `$` are the beginning and the ending of the string accordingly.

Comment: That worked! The more I try and escape regex the more it comes back at me